# Vuetify Child Router View displaying incorrectly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm trying to have a child router-view display as content for surrounding components.

My routing looks as follows:

```
{
    path: "/login",
    name: "TheLoginView",
    component: TheLoginView,
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "TheDashboard",
    component: () => import("@/views/TheDashboard"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        name: "DashboardView",
        component: () => import("@/components/dashboard/DashboardView"),
        children: [
          {
            name: "Place Order",
            path: "place-order",
            component: () => import("@/views/ThePlaceOrderView"),
          },
          {
            name: "Previous Orders",
            path: "Past-orders",
            component: () => import("@/components/ThePastOrders"),
          },
          {
            name: "Account Options",
            path: "account-options",
            component: () => import("@/components/TheAccountOptions"),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

My Dashboard component looks as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <DashboardAppBar />

    <DashboardNavDrawer />

    <DashboardView />

    <DashboardFooter />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

The issue I'm having is the DashboardView is being rendered below the navdrawer instead of the expected result which is next to it.

The result I'm getting with any combination of v-app or v-content is as follows:

[image: current result]

Currently the DashboardView component looks as follows:

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

I'm a bit lost as to what I need to be changing/adding/removing in order to get the child router-view to display next to the drawer

Comment: Take a look at one of the [pre-made layouts](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/pre-made-layouts/#pre-made-layouts), particularly the ["Complex"](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/complex/) one for an example similar to your needs.

Comment: @YomS. not sure exactly what to look at but I tried formatting my DashboardView as per the complex example but it didn't do much differently: https://i.imgur.com/u7jcsMZ.png

Comment: @YomS. Was able to get it working using the app prop for the relevant components, took me a bit to figure out that's what was missing. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the above using the 'app' prop for the components mentioned.

The below example uses my DashboardNavDrawer component where I added 'app to the  component:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer app class="deep-purple accent-4" dark permanent>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item
        class="mx-2"
        v-for="(item, index) in mainMenuItems"
        :key="index"
        link
        :to="item.to"
      >
        <v-list-item-icon>
          <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>
            {{ item.name }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

Adding this prop has made it look like the following screenshot which is the desired outcome:

[image: desired result achieved]

The comment provided by YomS. lead me to this answer so I'd like to express appreciation for his help!